# Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Loader: error in symfony 3

Tags: symfony

**i have created a new bundle in symfony and I got this error,**
can anyone help me?  i am using symfony 3,
check the error below:
 
 under SRC i have created the bundle 
and i have not changed any coding,
i edited the composer.jsone

> "autoload": {
>           "psr-4": {
>               "": "src/"
>           },
>           "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
>       },

and executed

> $ composer dump-autoload

and i got this error

> **Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Loader: "Unable to find template "NewSoftwareBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into: C:\xampp\htdocs\myfirstsym\app/Resources/views, C:\xampp\htdocs\myfirstsym\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form)." at C:\xampp\htdocs\myfirstsym\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php line 232**

Comment: Looks like you are using twig. Twig renders a twig file in the Render method, and it seems to not find the file specified on the render method

Comment: when i create the new bundle i get the error, when i am using appbundle(default) one itz working will, if u know how to create new bundle and print hello world without error , please let me know how

Comment: You are pointing to the wrong location for the index.html.twig from the error message update the your question with the folder structure and where you are making call to NewSoftwareBundle:Default:index.html.twig
i.e the controller that is calling the index

Comment: thank you for your reply frdz

Answer (score 1):

am assuming index.html.twig is in this directory

app/Resources/views/Default

Move this file

> index.html.twig

to

> \app/Resources/views